# Android:initiate the listView items

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listview` and take `TextView` as the list-item,now I need the first item's state to be selected when the listview has been initiated. In other words , i have give the `TextView` a `selector drawable` , so i want the item to be selected when it first shows in the list.
I wonder if i have made it clear.
Hope your help coming soon.
Thanks first!

PS: I add the list items by my own adapter extending from `SimpleAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Either [setSelection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29) or [singleChoiceList](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List10.html) is your answer.

Comment: Yeah,I've done this , but i found the item's bg still be unchanged.

Comment: Yeah.Here it is.'<ListView
     android:id="@+id/option_vfmonitor_list"
     android:divider="@color/list_divider"
     android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
     android:dividerHeight="1dp"
     android:scrollbars="none"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="400dp">
    </ListView>'

Comment: and here is the list_item.xml:  '                                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   style="@style/option_item_style"
   android:id="@+id/option_item"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:paddingLeft="15dp"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="48dp"
   android:background="@drawable/option_item_bg"
  /> '                                                                         the 'option_item_bg' is the 'selector'file ,which defines the state of the item.